# How is it possible for an item to have 300+ stat?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just saw an amulet on the Auction House with 325 Dexterity. I was under the impression that the max was 200, so I went into the DiabloNut affix page and looked for the Dex ones.

Apparently you can have only 100 Dexterity from the +Dex affix, but you can have up to 300 from DexVit, DexInt, etc.

Does this mean that the maximum possible on an item is 400? For one stat that is, I am sure you can't have 400 for multiple stats.

Comment: Does your site take into account that as of the 1.05 patch, rings and amulets can now generate iLvl 63 affixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primary stats are based on the equipment slot. For amulets the highest possible primary stat (str, dex, vit, int) is 350.  For an updated list on every possible stat check out this webpage: http://www.d3rmt.com/guides/diablo-3-item-stat-maximum-values/#primary-stats

Comment: Although the site you linked to has some errors, it seems to be correct about the primary stats. Does this mean that the data in [this page](http://diablonut.incgamers.com/affixes/adventure-and-stats) is incorrect or was I just interpreting it wrong?

I figured each equipment could get 100 Dex from the Dex 16 Secondary, and 300 Dex from each of the stat combinations (like DexVit).

Comment: the site you listed seems fine.  iggnoring bonuses from legendaries an ammulet can have a maximum of 150 dex from the prefixes marvelous, murderous or valient. while having a maximum bonus of 200 dex from the affex "of pain". this diffurs per inventory slot.

Comment: Yes it lists the correct values for the amulet but try looking for helm or shoulders, it doesn't match up.

Comment: Well for shoulders d3rmt says that the max primary stats are 200 dex/int/vit and 300 str. When filtering to only show shoulders on diablonut, it does not show some affixes/prefixes for example "of pain" and a quick auction house search of magic shoulders with above 150 dex will show that the affix "of pain" is applicable to shoulders. So, I would say that there are some inconsistencies with that website you are using.

Comment: Yea it seems to have some errors for main stat data for some armor but the rest are pretty solid. Thanks for the link.